# xsl:choose if a variable is a file or a folder

Tags: html, xslt

I like to check if my $name variable is a file or folder. I would like to use different icons. Something like an if/then statement. I think if $name has an extension then it's a file.

How do I check if $name has an extension and what kind of extension?

```
------------------
  if ${name} is a file then
    if ${name} has an rpm extension then
     <tr><td><img src='/.icons/rpm.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='{$name}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a></td><td><xsl:value-of select='$date'/></td><td align='right'><xsl:value-of select='$size'/></td></tr>
    else
     <tr><td><img src='/.icons/file.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='{$name}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a></td><td><xsl:value-of select='$date'/></td><td align='right'><xsl:value-of select='$size'/></td></tr>
   ifelse
     <tr><td><img src='/.icons/folder.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='{$name}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a></td><td><xsl:value-of select='$date'/></td><td align='right'><xsl:value-of select='$size'/></td></tr>
  fi
 fi
-------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Your theory that files names always include "." and directory names don't is of course quite wrong, though if you're content with something that works 90% of the time then it might be OK for your purposes. It's also wrong that the file name extension tells you what type of file it is: that's down to the media type (MIME type), not the extension.

If you're looking at local files (as distinct from HTTP resources) consider using the extension functions in the EXPath file module, if your processor supports them. See http://expath.org/spec/file - in particular `file:is-file()` and `file:is-dir()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with distinguishing the file/folder difference by the appearance of dots, you can apply the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

- It uses a recursive template to get the string after the last `/`.
- Then it checks if this string contains a `.`

So, for a sample XML file like this:

```
<root>
     <img src='/.icons/rpm.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' />
     <img src='/.icons/file.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' />
     <img src='/.icons/someDir' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' />
     <img src='/.icons/folder.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' />
     <img src='/.icons/anotherDir' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' />
</root>
```

the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" /> 

    <xsl:template match="/root/img">
        <xsl:variable name="filename">
            <xsl:call-template name="afterLastSlash">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="@src" />
            </xsl:call-template>  
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($filename,'.')">
                <xsl:value-of select="'File'" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'Directory'" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- get filename (string after last slash) -->
    <xsl:template name="afterLastSlash">
        <xsl:param name="str" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-after($str,'/') != ''">
                <xsl:call-template name="afterLastSlash">
                    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str,'/')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$str" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

yields the following result:

```
 File
 File
 Directory
 File
 Directory
```

---

With XSLT-2.0 or above the stylesheet can be reduced to

```
<xsl:template match="/root/img">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(replace(@src,'(.+/)?(.+)','$2'),'.')">
            <xsl:value-of select="'File'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Directory'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This solves it. I realized that directories have no size.

```
 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="($size = '')">
         <tr><td><img src='/.icons/folder.gif' alt='[DIR]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='{$name}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a></td><td><xsl:value-of select='$date'/></td><td align='right'><xsl:value-of select='$size'/></td></tr>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="(contains($name, '.rpm'))">
         <tr><td><img src='/.icons/rpm.png' alt='[   ]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='{$name}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a></td><td><xsl:value-of select='$date'/></td><td align='right'><xsl:value-of select='$size'/></td></tr>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
          <tr><td><img src='/.icons/unknown.gif' alt='[   ]' width='16' height='16' /></td><td><a href='{$name}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a></td><td><xsl:value-of select='$date'/></td><td align='right'><xsl:value-of select='$size'/></td></tr>
     </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```